# add to a queue result failure

Tags: c++, linked-list, queue

I am working on add an item to a queue, but always get a segmentation fault.

Here is my Node class:

```
    class Node{
private:
   int data;
   Node* next;
public:
   Node(int data);
   Node *getNext();
   void setNext(Node* next);
   int getData();
   void print();
   Node();
 };
   Node::Node(int data){this->data = data; this->next = NULL;}
   Node::Node(){this->data = 0; this->next = NULL;}
   void::Node::print(){cout << data;}
   Node*::Node::getNext(){return next;}
   int::Node::getData(){return data;}
   void::Node::setNext(Node* next){this->next = next;}
```

Here is my queue class:

```
   class Queue{
private:
   Node* head;
Node* tail;
  public:
void enter(int value);
Queue();
};


 Queue::Queue(){
  head = NULL;
  tail = NULL;
}

void Queue::enter(int item){
  Node* newNode = new Node(item);
  if(tail== NULL){
    head = newNode;
  }
  else{
    tail->setNext(newNode);
  }
  tail = newNode;
 }
```

Here is the main:

```
Queue* queue = new Queue;
queue->enter(5);
```

I am stuck in this for hours and could not figure out why...

```
    Node* newNode = new Node(item);
```

This is the line that I got segmentation fault.

Comment: What line does your debugger say causes the seg fault?

Comment: Node* newNode = new Node(item);

Comment: Hm, I can't see how that line would cause a seg fault.

Comment: At first and second glance, the code looks fine.  Are you certain that you have recompiled this code?  And you're running the result of that compilation?